# GA: Goals list API: webPropertyId='~all' query returns http 400 "webPropertyId" must be specified

Tags: python, google-analytics-api, goal-tracking

I am looping over Google Analytics account profiles using the management().goals() API and discovering what goals are created for each, to know what I can fetch data for. Having got a valid service instance I can make requests against, the goals().list() fails complaining of missing webPropertyId parameter:

```
# not including the ServiceAccountCredentials setup here
from apiclient.discovery import build
service = build('analytics', 'v3', http=http)
service.management().goals().list(accountId=account_id, webPropertyId='~all', profileId=profile_id)
```

The last line fails with:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/nnnnnnnnn/webproperties/%7Eall/profiles/nnnnnnnnn/goals?alt=json returned "webPropertyId must be specified.">
```

[I replaced the account/profile numbers after /accounts/ and /profiles/ with nnnnnnnnn for this post, for privacy; the real error has numbers there]

The relevent bit: `webPropertyId must be specified.`

I'm definitely supplying the `webPropertyId` parameter, and if I remove it I get a different error:

```
TypeError: Missing required parameter "webPropertyId"
```

I can successfully make requests to pull other metadata and user information and analytics data from the management api. What might be going wrong here? Am I not allowed to use the `~all` value here and must be more specific?

Comment: The account, web property, and view (profile) can be thought of as a hierarchical tree. An account has many web properties, a web property has many views (profiles). Thus it only makes sense to use the `~all` qualifier from the bottom of the tree up. If you know a view (profile) ID then you should also know the parent web property, as a view has only one property, thus specifying `~all` for a specific view (profile) id does not work. It would be better to design the code with the hierarchical tree as understood, perhaps by first calling `analytics.accountSummaries.list()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Works:**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/~all/webproperties/~all/profiles/~all/goals
```

**Also works**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/~all/webproperties/~all/profiles/73835159/goals
```

**Does not work.**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/41967536/webproperties/~all/profiles/73835159/goals
```

Response:

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"badRequest","message":"webPropertyId must be specified."}],"code":400,"message":"webPropertyId must be specified."}}
```

I am going to call this a bug  [Goals with ~all results in an error](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63380151) bug report filed i will bring it up with the team next week.

Comment: I would not call this a bug, but works as intended. The `~all` qualifier only makes sense to use from the bottom up. If you know a view ID then there is one and only one web property id. The `~all` is simply syntactic sugar; I would advice using `accountSummaries.list` as your first API call, then use that hierarchical structure as a known. It will also save you time as `~all` can get more expensive if the user has many accounts with many properties and many views.